# React Axios how to correctly pass in config as parameter?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Does anyone know how to pass in config in Axios?
It works when the option that is passed in is `"method:'GET'"`, but it won't work when options are `"method:'POST,data:jsondata"`. it returns error 500 with 'GET' method. Why is it still a 'GET' method, is there a workaround or I'm doing it wrong?
I want to call only this function when using Axios.

```
 fetchWithToken(url, options) {          
        const headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        if (this.loggedIn) {
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
            return axios(url, { headers, options })
                .then(response => { return response })
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: 500 means your server is not working properly

Comment: have you tried to put POST method in axios? Like axios(method: "POST", etc..)?

Comment: axios(url, { headers, method: 'POST', data: jsondata }),I tried this it works , but not when I call this function fetchWithToken(url,{method:'POST',data:jsondata}). My point is to call this function when calling API with different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax problem with your method. You are passing the object which has another object, which you should use as parameter in your axios request.

I would do it like this:

```
 fetchWithToken = (url, options)=>{          
  const headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  if (this.loggedIn) {
      headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
      return axios({url: url, headers: headers, data: options.data, method: options.method})
          .then(response => { return response })
   }
}

const obj = {method:'POST', data:""};
fetchWithToken(url, obj);
```

So you now can call `fetchWithToken(url,{method:'POST',data:jsondata})`

Comment: I have tried yours, but I still get an error with Get request I don't know why. The method I put in is 'POST'

Comment: Please, check the code now. I updated it. Let me know what result you have.

Comment: it works now Thx bro. Mistake on my part, your fetchWithToken(url, {method:'POST',data:jsondata}) works

Comment: @AlvinMathis no problem! Make sure to upvote answer. Wish you good luck :)

Comment: Quick question How does it works when I send in (url, "method:'GET' "), because we use object 'options' so options.method would be undefined, but It's working.

Comment: I thought the default would be 'GET' ,but when I send nothing fetchWithToken(url) it returns method undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
let postData = {
    // DATA FOR POST METHOD
}

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `YOUR_API_ENDPOINT`,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: {
        ...postData
    }
})
.then((res) => {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```